# Concat ng-repeat in jade templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug, mean

I'm developing a MEAN app, and I cannot insert ng-repeat item.property inside onclick parameters function.

Here's the code.

```
           tbody
            tr(ng-repeat="item in clientes")
                td {{ item.name }}
                td {{ item.badge }}
                td {{ item.dob }}
                td {{ item.isLoved }}
                td
                    button(name="borrar_blob", onclick="borrarBlob( {{ item._id }} )") Borrar
```

It's a simple question, but I'm new on jade and mongo.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the curly brackets {{ }}, like this:

```
onclick="borrarBlob(item._id)"
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( rendered HTML: <button name="borrar_blob" onclick="borrarBlob( {item._id} )">Borrar</button>

Comment: Make it ng-click="borrarBlob(item._id)" (And define your function within your controller)

Comment: Work's fine, but can you explain me why it's not possible bymy way? Just want to learn, not only find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Fair enough. onclick is not an Angular directive, ng-click is. Angular leaves the onclick attribute for what it is, but parses the ng-click attribute. I think it should be possible to use onclick as onclick="borrarBlob('{{item._id}}') (the '' make it a string), but you would need to have borrarBlob defined outside angular, as Angular does not recognise it as a scope function. Working with the item._id outside Angular probably does not make any sense at all, so always use ng-click :)